# iOs 5, initWithDecoder gets called before my custom init

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, initialization, uitabbar

I have a button. When you click on the button it will open up a new UITabBarController (pre-defined in toolbox).

This is the code:

```
DealerView *view = [[DealerView alloc] initWithDealerId:976];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

As you can see i use my own custom initializer to pass in an NSUInteger number to the UITabBarController.

Now inside my UITabBarController, i want to distribute this ID number to all children (all tabs in the tab-bar). I do this with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSInteger i;
    for (i = 0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++){
        DealerBaseView *item = (DealerBaseView*) [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        item.dealerId = self->dealerId;
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

That way each child view can use this id number to get the correct database information inside their own viewDidLoad method.

**The problem is that self->dealerId is always 0.**

So i added some break points inside my code to see why self->dealerId always returns 0 (you can see that it's set in the initialization method).

```
- (id) initWithDealerId:(NSUInteger)i{

    self = [super init];

    if (self){
        self->dealerId = i;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return self;
}
```

Now it turns out that the order of things in this is the following:

1. initWithCoder - UITabBarController
2. viewDidLoad - UITabBarController
3. viewDidLoad - Child tab of UITabBarController
4. initWithNibName - UITabBarController
5. viewDidLoad - UITabBarController (second time it hits this)
6. initWithDealerId - UITabBarController

So my init method gets called lastly in this serie and thus the dealerId will always be 0.

My question is simply. How can i set the dealerId so that it's available when viewDidLoad gets called for both the UITabVarController and UITabVarController items (all child items inside the tab controller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are creating two different DealerView objects in two different ways, one from a xib or storyboard and the other in code.  If you NSLog the value of self in the different init methods, I believe you'll see different addresses, which indicates different objects.  What you see as a single sequence of events really isn't.

The answer to your initialization question is to only use the one object.